# Optimizing GROUP BY in hsqldb

Tags: hsqldb

I have a table with 700K+ records on wich a simple GROUP BY query takes in excess of 35+ seconds to execute. I'm out of ideas on how to optimize this.

```
SELECT TOP 10 called_dn, COUNT(called_dn) FROM reportview.calls_out GROUP BY called_dn;
```

- Here I add `TOP 10` to limit network transfer induced delays.
- I have an index on `called_dn` (hsqldb seems not to be using this).
- `called_dn` is non nullable.
- `reportview.calls_out` is a cached table.

Here's the table script:

```
CREATE TABLE calls_out (
  pk_global_call_id INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS SEQUENCE seq_global_call_id NOT NULL,
  sys_global_call_id VARCHAR(65),
  call_start TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
  call_end TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
  duration_interval INTERVAL HOUR TO SECOND(0),
  duration_seconds INTEGER,
  call_segments INTEGER,
  calling_dn VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  called_dn VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  called_via_dn VARCHAR(25),
  fk_end_status INTEGER NOT NULL,
  fk_incoming_queue INTEGER,
  call_start_year INTEGER,
  call_start_month INTEGER,
  call_start_week INTEGER,
  call_start_day INTEGER,
  call_start_hour INTEGER,
  call_start_minute INTEGER,
  call_start_second INTEGER,
  utc_created TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
  created_by VARCHAR(25),
  utc_modified TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE,
  modified_by VARCHAR(25),
  PRIMARY KEY (pk_global_call_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (fk_incoming_queue)
    REFERENCES lookup_incoming_queue(pk_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (fk_end_status)
    REFERENCES lookup_end_status(pk_id));
```

I'm I stuck with this kind of performance or is there something I might try to speed up this query?

EDIT: Here's the query plan if it helps:

```
isDistinctSelect=[false]
isGrouped=[true]
isAggregated=[true]
columns=[  COLUMN: REPORTVIEW.CALLS_OUT.CALLED_DN not nullable
  COUNT  arg=[   COLUMN: REPORTVIEW.CALLS_OUT.CALLED_DN nullable]
  [range variable 1
    join type=INNER
    table=CALLS_OUT
    cardinality=771855
    access=FULL SCAN
    join condition = [index=SYS_IDX_SYS_PK_10173_10177]]]
groupColumns=[COLUMN: REPORTVIEW.CALLS_OUT.CALLED_DN]
offset=[VALUE = 0, TYPE = INTEGER]
limit=[VALUE = 10, TYPE = INTEGER]
PARAMETERS=[]
SUBQUERIES[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, as it seems there's no way to avoid a full column scan in this situation.

Just for reference of future souls reaching this question, here's what I resorted to in the end:

Created a summary table maintained by `INSERT` / `DELETE` triggers in the original table. This in combination with suitable indexes and using `LIMIT USING INDEX` clauses in my queries yields very good performance.